# Get polyline's length in point

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-polyline

I use google maps api vs3. I have drawing manager and when I clicked somewhere on polyline I get length of polyline and coordinates in this point.[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5r9mG.png).
I make it with code

```
google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeLength(polyline).getPath()
```

I need to calculate length from start polyline through path to mouse click. Is it possible?

Comment: [Proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/mqLLfwpq/2/)

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/mqLLfwpq/2/) - perfect for me